# Why is `for...in` returning a tuple when trying to iterate through rows returned by query?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

I select 1 column from a table in a database. I want to iterate through each of the results. Why is it when I do this it’s a tuple instead of a single value?

```
con = psycopg2.connect(…)
cur = con.cursor()
stmt = "SELECT DISTINCT inventory_pkg FROM {}.{} WHERE inventory_pkg IS NOT NULL;".format(schema, tableName)
cur.execute(stmt)
con.commit()
referenced = cur.fetchall()
for destTbl in referenced:#why is destTbl a single element tuple? 
    print('destTbl: '+str(referenced))
    stmt = "SELECT attr_name, attr_rule FROM {}.{} WHERE ppm_table_name = {};".format(schema, tableName, destTbl)#this fails because the where clause gets messed up because ‘destTbl’ has a comma after it
    cur.execute(stmt)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's what the db api does: always returns a tuple for each row in the result.

It's pretty simple to refer to `destTbl[0]` wherever you need to.

Comment: Still don't get it. Yes `fetch*()` returns a tuple but, shouldn't `for x in y:` make `x` not a tuple?

Comment: No, it's a tuple *for each row*.

Comment: I guess I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are getting *rows* from your database, and the API is being consistent.

If your query asked for `*` columns, or a specific number of columns that is *greater* than 1, you'd also need a tuple or list to hold those columns for each row.

In other words, just because you only have one column in *this* query doesn't mean the API suddenly will change what kind of object it returns to model a row.

Simply always treat a row as a sequence and use indexing or tuple assignment to get a specific value out. Use:

```
inventory_pkg = destTbl[0]
```

or

```
inventory_pkg, = destTbl
```

for example.